# Custom Binary File - Read from hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a fixed length binary file. The record is something like:

```
[Field1:int, Field2:double, Field3: int, ....]
```

How can i make this file to be an input to my map reduce job? 
Do i nead to write my custom InputFormat?
Does anyone can post an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that exists a class called FixedLengthInputFormat! It works well!
I can pass the length of the record to it. The mapper receives as input value a BytesWritable (kind of array of bytes) and the i just unserialize it to an object.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FixedLengthInputFormat.html